# get_posts returning empty array

Tags: get-posts

I am building a custom WordPress function/plugin that uses get_posts.  The following code returns an empy array.  I have included wp-load.php in my script.  Is there something else I am missing?

```
$args = array(
    "posts_per_page"   => -1,
    "paged"            => 0,
    "orderby"          => "post_date",
    "order"            => "DESC",
    "post_type"        => "carellcars, ccf, attachment",
    "post_status"      => "publish, inherit",
    "post_author"       => "2"

);

$posts_array = get_posts($args); 

print_r($posts_array);

die;
```

If I use arrays for post_type and _status the array is not populated, but if I use single values for post_type and _status the array is populated?

Not populated:

```
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'paged'            => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => array('carellcars', 'ccf', 'attachment'),
    'post_status'      => array('publish', 'inherit')
);
```

Populated:

```
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'paged'            => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type' =>  'carellcars',
    'post_status'      => 'publish'
);
```

Update, removing "ccf" post type produces results, but I do have a ccf post_type and would like to include them.  Any ideas?

```
    'post_type' => array('carellcars', 'attachment'),
    'post_status'      => array('publish', 'inherit')
```

Comment: Try removing `meta_key` and `meta_value` entirely. What you're asking for here is for all posts that have an empty meta key with an empty meta value actually saved.

Comment: If you're building a plugin, why are you including `wp-load,php`? Is this not running inside of WP somewhere?

Comment: It's a lot easier if you make the actual plugin (it only requires a one-line comment at the top of the file) and activate it from wp-admin. That gives you all of WP's built-in functionality without having to try to include external files.

Comment: `post_status` should be a comma-separated string instead of an array: `'post_type' => 'carrellcars,ccf,attachment'`. However post type states "only hierarchical post types are valid" - you may not be able to pull multiple post types with `get_posts()`. You could try a `WP_Query()` instead.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: If you want to test the code, put it e.g. in the file `footer.php`, this is the easiest way. I checked, `post_type` can not be a string containing several types separated by a comma. After changing `post_type` to an array, the query works.

Comment: Changing the post status and types to an array produced no output for me.  Changing them to a single value DOES produce output.  I am running a slightly older version of WordPress.

Comment: $args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'paged'            => 0,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => array('carellcars', 'ccf', 'attachment'),
    'post_status'      => array('publish', 'inherit')

);  The above returns empty for me.

Comment: You should [edit] the details in your answer into the question itself, or ask a new one if the answers did not suffice

Comment: I have edited the original question.  In addition, I posted a new question but it was marked as duplictate.  Frustrating lol.  Lunch helped.

Comment: After changing `post_type` into array all parameters looks OK. `'paged' => 0` it is not necessary,  but rather does not affect the results. If you have any page or "blog" post, try with `'post_type' => [ 'page', 'carellcars' ],` or `'post'` instead `'page'`.

Comment: Do you mean like this?  'post_type' => array('post', 'carellcars', 'ccf', 'attachment'),  If so, that produced no results for me also.

Comment: No, query works with single post type `'carellcars'`, try with `array('carellcars')`, next with `array('carellcars', 'page')` or `array('carellcars', 'post')`. As I wrote earlier, when the post type is an array, I can see the results. I do not know why it is different with you. The trial and error method remains.

Comment: "I am running a slightly older version of WordPress." - what version? And `get_posts()` by default suppresses all filters, but for better troubleshooting, try `$q = new WP_Query( $args ); var_dump( $q->request, $q->post_count );` and compare the `var_dump()` output - 1) when using single post type and status, and 2) when using multiple post types and statuses.

Comment: Removing "ccf" post type produces results.  This is the issue, but why is this happening?  I have a ccf type?

Comment: @JobbieDaddy, try [this](https://gist.github.com/5ally/b1baaf804f3a18347fdfc96ccc2a31bb) and in each `WP_Query` call, inspect the SQL query and post count - do you see the proper query and post count based on the provided `$args` ?

Comment: I've implemented your code here:  https://100.26.44.193.xip.io/espanol_copy_test.php  I also Included a screenshot of my posts table showing 2 records with "ccf" post type

Comment: This isn't supposed to be there: `AND wp_posts.post_name = ''` (see the `with_ccf` row)... And although I'm not positive about this, try setting `suppress_filters` to `true` - see the updated [gist](https://gist.github.com/5ally/b1baaf804f3a18347fdfc96ccc2a31bb). But if you're still seeing the same `post_name = ''`, please try disabling all plugins and/or try a default theme.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
"post_type" => array('carellcars', 'ccf', 'attachment'),
```